# What is the difference between "Location" and "path" in hive tables

Tags: hive

When describing a table in hive, I get two paths in the description of the table.

```
hive> MSCK REPAIR TABLE default.am_test;
OK
Time taken: 0.061 seconds
...
...
Location:               hdfs://privacynameservice/anonymized/master/ste/finished/sessions    
...
...
# Storage Information            
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
Storage Desc Params:    
    path                    hdfs:/anonymized/master/ste/finished/sessions
    serialization.format    1    
Time taken: 0.048 seconds, Fetched: 57 row(s)
```

When I try to execute `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` on a remote spark2-shell (pointing to this hive instance with

```
--conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris=thrift://machine8068.dint.company.com:9083
```

It goes wrong, complaining that

```
scala> sql("MSCK REPAIR TABLE privacygateway.ste_catchup_v2")
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs:/anonymized/master/ste/finished/sessions does not exist.
```

So the repair command uses this second path that holds an odd URI, because it's not containing all three `///` nor the nameservice.

So... what is this `path` and why is it containing a path that I didn't set as such?